# Provide algorithm for solving $AX=B$ by finding $LU$ factorization using gaussian elimination then compute forward and backward substitutions

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra

I know there's many iterations of algorithms that solve the standard linear system $A\vec{x}=b$ by gaussian elimination with partial pivoting. I looked at them for guidance, but I just want to make sure that for this case the algorithm to be is also going to be correct

In this case we consider $A$ nonsingular n-by-n and B is n-by-m

So the algorithm goes this way, we obtain the unique $PLU$ factorization, where $P$ is permutation matrix. We then proceed to solve $LUX=P^{-1}B$ by forward substitution and lastly proceed to solve $UX=L^{-1}(P^{-1}B)$ by backward substitution.

Any links to algorithms for the standard case could be helpful or your input into how to proceed.

Since $\vec{x}$ and $b$ have been converted from vectors to matrices in this case, I'm assuming the algorithm won't change much with the exception of an addition for loop that runs parallel

Answer (score 1):

You are not writing the systems to be solved in a perceptive way... The roadmap is:

1. Find $Y$, solution of $L Y = P^{-1}B$;
2. Find $X$, solution of $UX = Y$.